# Recommendation for genealogy software for OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, software-recommendation

I primarily work with gedcom files for my genealogy. What software is available for the mac which allows me to view and edit gedcom genealogy files?

If there are several options, I'd like one that interfaces with ancestry.com and/or other similar sites so I don't have to quite as much work managing searches and downloads of gedcom files.

Icing on the cake would include apps that have ipad counterparts so I can take it on the go for at least viewing, and hopefully editing.

I'm fine with apps that have their own database or file format as long as they import and export gedcom as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven’t found one that interfaces with the website you mentioned, but here’s a good overview of genealogy software for OS X: http://www.macgenealogy.org/mac-genealogy-software/

[**MacFamilyTree 6**](http://www.macgenealogy.org/macfamilytree-6) is actively developed (it was just updated a few days ago), is [fully GEDCOM-compatible](http://www.syniumsoftware.com/macfamilytree/publish.html), and it has an iOS version too!

[image: Screenshot]

It doesn’t export to ancestry.com but it can interface with a custom-built website called MacFamilyTree.com.

Comment: Upvote for MacFamilyTree in terms of functionality - I really don't like their UI.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried many, and my favourite is iFamily, which is weirdly called [iFamily for Leopard](http://www.ifamilyforleopard.com/index.php) as it's full name, but it works fine in Lion.

It had full GEDCOM support, and the only demo limitation is the lack of export to GEDCOM, so you can try it in full more or less without buying.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try '[Reunion](http://www.leisterpro.com/)', which has GEDCOM import/export and is available for iPad and iPhone too.

Comment: J.C. Are you interested in the Genealogy Q&A site that's starting at Area 51? It needs just a few more committers with 200+ rep to get to Beta. If you're interested, please sign up. The Genealogy proposal is at: http://bit.ly/U3vnDX Sorry to post this as a comment here, but it was the only way I could find to contact you.

Answer (score 0):

GenealogyJ is cross-platform (jar executable) and fully free.

As the accepted answer mentioned, MacFamilyTree is beautiful. Also MyHeritage Family Tree Builder has its uses (specifically exporting nice fan charts).